# Spacy language model installation in python returns ImportError (ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.)

Tags: spacy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sathish.pv\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "c:\users\sathish.pv\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "c:\users\sathish.pv\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\sathish.pv\Envs\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "C:\Users\sathish.pv\Envs\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

```
I have tried reinstalling spaCy package using "pip install spacy" but still end up getting the same error. How do I deal with this? I am using python version 3.7.4, Windows 10
```

I tried using the following spacy installation methods. But get the same error

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

- pip install spacy
- pip install -U spacy
- python -m spacy validate

Comment: You should definitely add the code you're using to initialize the library. Otherwise, we don't know what has led to the error.

Comment: I tried using pip install spacy

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to struggle to get help here unless you include something reproducible. You've included the error message but with very little context it'll be hard to provide you with help. I've asked for your initialization code which you haven't yet given.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was resolved by installing Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

You can download it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145.

Answer (score 1):

*(This would actually be better off in a comment to Kumar Rajwani's answer, but I don't have enough reputation for comments yet)*

For me it also got fixed by installing a (different) version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

But: Apparently, it is **important** to distinguish **which build version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015** to install. And if you already have a newer version on your computer than the one linked in Kumar Rajwani's answer, you cannot install the older version without temporarily uninstalling the newer version. And you should definitely reinstall it, because a redistributable package comes with a specific application that needs it for its work. **What works best for me** so far: Download and install **all versions in one package.** https://www.techpowerup.com/download/visual-c-redistributable-runtime-package-all-in-one/